# if doesn't work in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, numbers

I use this function to validate one input element :

```
function validerInput(qte, qtemax) {
    var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;
    if (floatRegex.test(qte.value)) {
        var a = qte.value;
        var b = qtemax;
        if (a > b) {
            alert('if qtemax : ' + qtemax + ', qte : ' + qte.value);
            qte.value = '';
        }
        else {
            alert('else qtemax : ' + qtemax + ', qte : ' + qte.value);
        }
    }
    else {
        qte.value = '';
    }
}
```

but the problem is always the alert of else is launched and the first never I don't know the problem

do you have any idea :

the alert that is launched contains for example 234 and 5.66

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value` property of an input element is stored as a string, so if you want to treat it as a number you'll need to convert it to one. You may have a similar issue with the value of `qtemax` too, it's impossible to say. Comparing strings alphabetically "234" comes before "5.66", then though numerically it's (much) greater. Use the [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function:

```
var a = parseFloat(qte.value),
    b = parseFloat(qtemax);
```